# publicRuntimeConfig in Nextjs not working client-side

Tags: next.js

In my `next.config.js` I have the following configuration:

```
    module.exports = {
      publicRuntimeConfig: {
        // Will be available on both server and client
        GRAPHQL_URL: process.env.API_URL,
      },
     }
```

and my scripts look like the following:

```
"build": "next build",
"start": "API_URL=some-url next start",
```

Now after running `npm run start` and using `{ publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()` in my code

`publicRuntimeConfig` contains `GRAPHQL_URL` server-side, but it's an empty object on the client-side.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using `getInitialProps`? `publicRuntimeConfig` will not be available unless you use `getInitialProps`:

> A page that relies on publicRuntimeConfig must use getInitialProps to
> opt-out of Automatic Static Optimization. Runtime configuration won't
> be available to any page (or component in a page) without
> getInitialProps.